# How to do multi-threading in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, gcdasyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

Sorry about the vague title of this question, I couldn't think of a concise sentence to explain the problem I'm having.

Basically I want to start multiple threads and pass an object with thread-specific values that I can use within that context. Here is the code that does that

```
while (count < no_threads) {
    _thread_bytes = _file_length / no_threads;
    _thread_offset = count * _thread_bytes;

    NSDictionary *args = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:_thread_offset],@"thread_offset",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:_thread_bytes], @"thread_bytes",
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:count], @"count", nil];

    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(processServerThread:) object:args];
    [thread start];
    count++;
}
```

Each thread calls the selector method with the correct `thread_bytes` and `thread_offset` and also has access to a `GCDAsyncSocket` socket, this consequently results in many delegate method calls that use the `thread_bytes` and `thread_offset`. Here is the selector method.

```
- (void)processServerThread:(id)sender
{    
    NSError *err;

    dispatch_queue_t iQueue = dispatch_queue_create("main_server_queue", NULL);

    GCDAsyncSocket *socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:iQueue];

    if (![socket connectToHost:@"example.com" onPort:8080 error:&err]) {

        NSLog(@"Error: couldn't connect to file server....");

        return;
    }

    NSData *message =[[self requestMessageWithOffset:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_thread_offset]
                            andBytes:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_thread_bytes]]
                            dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [socket writeData:message withTimeout:SOCKET_TIMEOUT tag:TAG_FILE_REQUEST_WRITE];
}
```

If there are N threads being processed, when I send the request message the value of `_thread_offset`, for example if offsets are 0, 2, 4, 8. It shows 0 for one thread an 8 for all other threads, while they should have each a unique offset within that context.

Also, is there any callback method for when a thread finishes?

Comment: The very first thing to do is to read and understand the documentation for GCD (Grand Central Dispatch), if you want to do any serious work with multiple threads. It is rarely a good idea to create an NSThread instead of using GCD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear to me why you're creating these threads at all. The entire point behind `GCDAsyncSocket` is to do asynchronous socket communications for you. It seems unnecessary to create your own threads, have each launch asynchronous write tasks.

In fact, as I read your code sample, your threads will terminate as soon as the asynchronous write has been initiated (but likely before the write is finished), which I do not think was your intent.

Setting that aside, you ask:

> It shows 0 for one thread an 8 for all other threads, while they should have each a unique offset within that context.

As sahara108 pointed out, you're referencing the instance variables `_thread_offset` and `_thread_bytes` rather than accessing the values that you added to the dictionary you passed to your thread. You should retrieve these values from the dictionary you passed to the thread.

> Also, is there any callback method for when a thread finishes?

You can observe `NSThreadWillExitNotification` (and obviously write a `willEndThread` method):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEndThread:) name:NSThreadWillExitNotification object:nil];
```

You obviously have to write a `willEndThread` method, too.

But you've specified `self` as the `delegate` for `GCDAsyncSocket`, so if you're looking for the completion of the write requests, you should implement those delegate methods.

---

Glancing at the `GCDAsyncSocket` source, it looks like they want you to use a serial queue. So, if you want to have concurrent requests going, you might try something like the following:

```
_thread_bytes = _file_length / no_threads;
for (int i = 0; i < no_threads; i++) {
    _thread_offset = i * _thread_bytes;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        BOOL success = [self processRequestWithOffset:_thread_offset byteCount:_thread_bytes];

        if (!success) {
            // do here whatever you want if the connection was unsuccessful
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
- (BOOL)processRequestWithOffset:(NSInteger)offset byteCount:(NSInteger)byteCount
{    
    NSError *error;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("main_server_queue", NULL);

    GCDAsyncSocket *socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:queue];

    if (![socket connectToHost:@"example.com" onPort:8080 error:&error]) {    
        NSLog(@"Error: couldn't connect to file server: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }

    NSData *message = [[self requestMessageWithOffset:@(offset)
                                             andBytes:@(byteCount)
                                    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [socket writeData:message withTimeout:SOCKET_TIMEOUT tag:TAG_FILE_REQUEST_WRITE];

    return YES;
}
```

And if you want to know if each of the connections finished successfully, just implement the relevant `GCDAsyncSocket` delegate methods.

Personally, I'll be interested in seeing if this is any faster than doing a normal post of the data with pipelining turned on. I'm also not terribly familiar with the idiosyncrasies of `GCDAsyncSocket`, so I don't know if there are deeper reasons why they don't want you to use a concurrent queue, but the above might be a way to create multiple instances of `GCDAsyncSocket` without delving into `NSThread` (GCD or operation queues are generally preferable to `NSThread`; see [Migrating Away From Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide*).

One final observation. I know that with `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` that there is a limit as to how many concurrent network requests you can do (generally 4 or 5), so you might be wary of using too many `GCDAsyncSocket` instances, too.

Comment: I appear to be using GCDAsyncSocket wrongly, thanks for the clarification. So instead if I make N number of socket connections, how do I make sure the write operations are accessing the correct values at the right time?

Comment: @LibanAbdulle I'm happy to help if I can, but perhaps we should step back and you can update your question and describe what you're trying to do. My answer just addressed a simple logical inconsistency in the existing question (no need to create threads to initiate an task that is already asynchronous). But the more fundamental question is why are you doing socket-level communications to a port that is usually reserved for HTTP requests. That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Furthermore, inferring from your code sample, you're trying to concurrently write blocks of a file to a socket. But I don't see anything in your socket protocol that would inform the socket which block you're writing. Perhaps that's encapsulated by your method for making the request, but I cannot tell. I simply cannot make sense of your code sample, so perhaps you can step back and describe what you're trying to do, and then we can help you solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I'm trying to do is file transfer through multiple sockets simultaneously. I'm using a custom protocol based on the Type-Length-Value pattern to communicate messages and data with a Python server. At the moment it works fine on one socket, but I want to scale that to whatever optimal connections it takes.

So the question is how do I use GCDAsyncSocket to create multiple instances, and send a range of bytes for a certain offset simultaneously.

Comment: Also the blocks of code in the OP has to do with the file download portion.

Comment: @LibanAbdulle I've updated my answer with a GCD implementation. Re your custom protocol, you say it includes Type-Length-Value. Don't you need "offset" or some similar identifier to specify which block it is? Or is that what you mean by "Type"?

Comment: Thanks for the update. The "type" is an identifier for the message itself, the offset is returned within Value which is an appended JSON payload containing details for the requested file. The process is a series of request messages, acks, and so on. All of which is dealt with within the delegate callbacks using tags. I'm currently at home, and haven't committed my code so I can't test your method until tomorrow. It's my first time ever dealing with threads and sockets, so I'm really grateful for the help.

Comment: @LibanAbdulle By the way, while I show you a GCD implementation of the code in your question, there's still an open question in my mind about why you would use sockets rather than issuing HTTP `POST` requests. But I presume you have a reason for doing it with sockets, but I always find it easier to use HTTP, and only use sockets where I need to keep an open connection (e.g. chat app or the like).

Comment: I've just tested out your implementation, and it works fine. One final thing: in the delegate method that gets called for reading the data from the socket --- I write to a file given the offset when the connection is made. But by the time I reference `_thread_offset` in the delegate method it's already changed. How do I effectively lock _thread_offset for each connection made?

Comment: @LibanAbdulle Two approaches: The easy solution is to simply subclass `GCDAsyncSocket` and add a property to your subclass to save the `_thread_offset`. That's not quite right architecturally, and probably better is use a different delegate object for each of the requests, and put your offset property there. Personally, I'd wrap the request in a concurrent `NSOperation` object that (a) has offset property; (b) is the delegate for the request; and (c) issues the async write.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is parameter of your `requestMessageWithOffset:`. You should use `sender[@"thread_offset"]` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:_thread_offset]`
. Also for `thread_bytes`.
For the callback you should look up in `GCDAsyncSocket protocol`

Answer (score 0):

Now use GCD to achieve this, have a look on below

Step-1: Create the Queue using dispatch_queue_create
Step-2: Add the Block and call dispatch_async

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue", NULL);

dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"Running code in secondary thread...");

    int value = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<100; j++) {
            for (int n=0; n<100; n++) {
                value += j;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"From secondary thread: value = %d", value);
});
```